# Can I leave India and return using a different passport? (Tourist Visa)

Tags: visas, india, uk-citizens, dual-nationality, new-zealand-citizens

I have dual citizenship to both NZ and the UK and am currently in India on my NZ visa which expires in March. I would like to continue travelling here but my NZ passport now has less than six months validity on it meaning I won't be granted a visa.

Can I leave India and return using my UK passport? (say if I went to Sri Lanka and got a visa in my UK passport there?)

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, you can.  The "two-month gap" rule between tourist visas was [abolished](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/Government-eases-visa-norms-for-tourists/articleshow/17471324.cms) for most nationalities (including NZ and UK) in 2012, which means that as long as your new passport has more than 6 months validity, you're welcome back.  Even if they did still care, in practice, they're unlikely to be able to match your two passports together.